# When you format a RAID array using mdadm do you lose all data on the primary hard drive?

Tags: raid, software-raid

I'm trying to create a software RAID array using my computer, which has 200 GB free space, a 1 TB USB external hard drive, and a 2 TB USB external hard drive using mdadm.

[These](http://www.mysolutions.it/tutorial-mdadm-software-raid-ubuntu-debian-systems/) directions instruct you to format the RAID array after creation.

By following the directions and formatting the RAID array do I lose all data on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will lose all data on whatever partitions you include in the RAID set.  If you make a mistake when creating the array and format it before you catch the mistake, you very well could.  Since this sounds like your first time creating a RAID array, I'd suggest making sure you have at least one, preferably two or more, verified good backups of all the data you care about before proceeding just in case.

Generally, think of creating or deleting a RAID array like creating/deleting partitions / volumes on your hard drive: whatever was there before is, or soon will be, gone.  The only difference is that RAID involves multiple drives.  If you have multiple partitions on each of the drives and only use one existing partition per drive for the array, only those partitions would be erased.  But if you make a mistake (my first point) and specify the wrong partition... well, that's why you make backups first.

Comment: Accurate, informative, succinct, quite the answer. Many thanks!